# React - Como modificar um estado do componente pai a partir do filho?

Tags: javascript, front-end, react

Digamos que eu tenho um componente pai:

```
import React from 'react';
import style from './style.less';

export default class Wrapper extends Component {

    this.state = {
         active: false
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <section className={style.wrapper}>
                <h2>{props.text}</h2>
                <div className={style.main}>
                     <Button isCentered={true} text="Precisa de alguma ajuda?" bgColor="#673ab7" color="white" />
                </div>
            </section>
        )
    }
);

export default Wrapper;
```

E um componente filho:

```
import React from 'react';
import style from './style.less';

const Button = (props) => (
    <div class={style.button} style={{textAlign: `${props.isCentered ? "center" : "left"}`}}>
         <a onClick={console.log("Clicou!")} style={{backgroundColor: `${props.bgColor}`, color: `${props.color}`}} class={style.a}>{props.text}</a>
    </div>
);

export default Button;
```

Meu `App.js`:

```
import { react, Component } from 'react';
import Header from './Wraper';

export default class App extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="app">
                <Wraper text="Lorem Ipsum" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

De que maneira eu posso modificar o estado `active` do component `Wrapper` para `true` no momento que eu clicar no componente filho `Button`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Você pode usar funções de `callbackParent()`:

Existem frameworks para lidar com o gerenciamento de estado, como por exemplo o Redux. Mas se a ideia não for adicionar um novo modulo no seu projeto, talvez você possa usar funções de callback:

Você pode passar como `props` para o componente filho uma função que irá chamar um método da sua classe statefull.

```
import React from 'react';
import style from './style.less';

export default class App extends Component {

    this.state = {
        active: false
    }

    // Função chamada pelo callbackParent();
    onChildChanged(bool) {
        this.setState({active: bool});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <section className={style.wrapper}>
                <h2>{props.text}</h2>
                <div className={style.main}>
                    <Button callbackParent={(bool) => onChildChanged(bool)} isCentered={true} text="Precisa de alguma ajuda?" bgColor="#673ab7" color="white" />
                </div>
            </section>
        )
    }
);

export default Wrapper;
```

Não se esqueça de chamar a sua função no `onClick()` do seu componente filho:

```
import React from 'react';
import style from './style.less';

const Button = (props) => (
    <div class={style.button} style={{textAlign: `${props.isCentered ? "center" : "left"}`}}>
         <a onClick={props.callbackParent(true))} style={{backgroundColor: `${props.bgColor}`, color: `${props.color}`}} class={style.a}>{props.text}</a>
    </div>
 );

 export default Button;
```