# Pegar state do componente filho no react

Tags: javascript, react

Como faço para pegar um state de um componente filho?

No meu exemplo eu tenho o Shell.js que é o componente pai:

```
  class Shell extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav propsdaNav={1} />
        <SupermarketDetail />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Shell;
```

Quero pegar o `state` do componente `<SupermarketDetail />` e o aplicar o retorno como `props` no componente `<Nav />` ao invés do número 1.

O SupermarketDetail.js está assim:

```
class SupermarketDetail extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            detailState: 0
        }
    }
    handleState(number) {
        this.setState({ detailState: number });
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.handleState(1)
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.handleState(0)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="containerDetail">
          ....
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default SupermarketDetail;
```

Queria receber no componente pai esse `detailState`. Alguma ideia?

Comment: Você pode definir o estado no componente pai, criar um método no pai que atualize esse estado e passar via props para o filho.

Comment: [React - Como modificar um estado do componente pai a partir do filho?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272228)

Comment: Uma exemplo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-v7jeqm

Comment: Da mesma forma, eu precisaria da informação que vem do componente filho

Comment: Do filho para pai não será possível ( até aonde sei ) se não for como já comentado. Em seu método `handleState` execute o método do pai passando como parâmetro `number` .. Mais seria melhor criar o estado no pai, assim evita duplicação de código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode criar um estado específico para transitar esse número no componente pai, além de um método que vai até o componente filho (via `props`) e altera esse estado definido anteriormente. Com o estado alterado, você fornece, via `props` também, o valor para o componente `<Nav />`.

Então, o seu componente pai seria algo como

```
class Shell extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        detailState: 1
    }

    this.setDetailState = this.setDetailState.bind(this);
  }

  setDetailState(detailState) {
    this.setDetailState({
      detailState
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav propsdaNav={this.state.detailState} />
        <SupermarketDetail detailStateCallback={this.setDetailState} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Shell;
```

Veja que escrevi um método chamado `setDetailState` no componente pai, que altera o estado desse mesmo componente. Toda vez que esse método for executado, ele vai alterar o estado que, por sua vez, provoca o *rerender*.

Já no componente filho (`<SupermarketDetail>`), basta você invocar o método do componente pai via `props`. De uma maneira simplificada, seria algo como

```
class SupermarketDetail extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      detailState: 0
    }
  }

  // Se você estiver setando o valor aqui
  handleState(number) {
    this.setState({ detailState: number });
    this.props.detailStateCallback(number);
  }

  // ...
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="containerDetail">
        {/* .... */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default SupermarketDetail;
```

Veja que no componente filho estou executando o método que forneci via `props`. Como disse anteriormente, esse método vai alterar o estado do componente pai, e fazer com que o componente `<Nav />` receba o valor.

Comment: Cara, muito bom!! Entendi o que você fez, me ajudou demais
Porém ele da o erro "too much recursion"
Acredito que é porque estou chamando o handleState(number) no componentDidMount e passando um valor

Comment: é, aí a coisa pode ser mais complicada. só garanta que vc não está setando o estado em lugares do ciclo de vida que a renderização cause uma mudança de estado, pq a mudança de estado provoca o render, aí vc entra em um loop mesmo

Answer (score 0):

Resposta está tendo limite da pilha por recursividade

```
setDetailState(detailState) {
this.setDetailState({
  detailState
})
```

}

pode corrigir usando:

```
setDetailState(detailState) {
this.setState(...this.state.datailState, {
  detailState
})
```

}