# Iniciante no React. Pegar dados digitado no Input

Tags: typescript, react, front-end

Olá

Eu estou estudando o ReactJs… e fiz a seguinte estrutura:

[code]

```
 class MyNascimento extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
     super(props);

     this.state = {      
       nascimentoValue: null,      
     };
   }

   render() {
     return (
       <div className="telaNascimento">

                 <span className="p-float-label">
                   <InputMask
                     id="nascimento"
                     size={20}
                     className={css.txtcampos}
                     mask="99/99/9999"
                     slotChar="__/__/____"
                     value={this.state.nascimentoValue}
                     onChange={event => {
                       this.setState({
                         nascimentoValue: event.target.value
                       });
                     }}
                   />
                   <label htmlFor="nascimento">Nascimento</label>
                 </span>

         {/* Fim telaNascimento */}
       </div>
     );
   }
 }

 class RegistroClientes extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);

     this.state = {
       nascimentoValue: null
     };
   }

 render() {
     return (
       <div className={css.fundo}>

  <MyNascimento
             valueNascimento={this.state.nascimentoValue}
             handleClick={this.clickProximo}

           />

         {/* FIM DA DIV FUNDO PRINCIPAL */}
       </div>
     );
   }
 }

 export default RegistroClientes;
```

[/code]

Como eu faço para pegar o que foi digitado no componente MyNascimento e jogar na variável nascimento que esta em RegistroClientes?

Comment: Solução foi baseado nesse tópico:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/339852/pegar-state-do-componente-filho-no-react

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so]! Não adicione "Resolvido" no título. Sei que é uma prática comum em muitos fóruns, mas aqui funciona diferente. Se encontrou a solução, basta usar o campo de resposta abaixo e vc mesmo [coloca a solução encontrada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Não esqueça de colocar os passos detalhados que vc fez (veja mais em [answer]), pois a ideia é que a resposta seja útil para qualquer pessoa que tenha o mesmo problema e visite o site futuramente. Depois, basta vc [aceitar a resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052), e ela estará "resolvida" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tudo certo?

Acredito que já tenha encontrado sua resposta mas vai a solução de qualquer forma.
Neste caso para efetuar os testes eu fiz com que a label do input preenchesse o valor passado pelo pai.

Testei aqui tudo certo.

**COMPONENTE PAI:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import MyNascimento from "./Components/MyNascimento";

class RegistroClientes extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      nascimentoValue: null
    };
  }

  // Função a ser chamada pelo seu componente filho
  handleChildChange(valorDoFilho) {
    this.setState({ nascimentoValue: valorDoFilho });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyNascimento
          nascimentoValue={this.state.nascimentoValue}
          funcaoDoPai={valorDoFilho => this.handleChildChange(valorDoFilho)}
        />

        {/* FIM DA DIV FUNDO PRINCIPAL */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RegistroClientes;

ReactDOM.render(<RegistroClientes />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**COMPONENTE FILHO:**

```
import React from "react";

const MyNascimento = props => (
  <div>
    <span>
      <input
        id="nascimento"
        size={20}
        mask="99/99/9999"
        slotChar="__/__/____"
        value={props.nascimentoValue}
        onChange={event => {
          props.funcaoDoPai(event.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <label htmlFor="nascimento">{props.nascimentoValue}</label>
    </span>

    {/* Fim telaNascimento */}
  </div>
);

export default MyNascimento;
```

Espero ter ajudado. Abraços!